# what is difference between these two Date_Format function in MySql query?

Tags: mysql, group-by

select .....
where
    a.DateCreated between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
group by a.StoreID , b.ProductID , DATE_FORMAT(a.DateCreated, '%m')

and

select ....
where
    a.DateCreated between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
group by a.StoreID , b.ProductID , DATE_FORMAT(a.DateCreated, '%Y-%m')

Answer (score 1):

the first is just month

- and you get a maximum of 12 rows for each combination of a.StoreID ,
  b.ProductID in the result

the second is year and month (this is probably better by the way)

- and you get 12 monthly rows **for each year** and each combination of a.StoreID ,b.ProductID in the result

**however!**

do NOT use between for date rage filtering, and do NOT use 23:59:59 as the end of the day because it isn't, a much better way is:

```
where a.DateCreated >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' 
and a.DateCreated < '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: will it affect  any difference in output if yes then explain what ?

Comment: you are filtering for 2 years of data. (2014 & 2015) if you want a rows for year & month then use year & month, if you only want rows for month use month. the difference is the number of rows the 2 queries will produce. My guess is you should use year & month

Comment: but it's producing the same result just order is changed .and my data is huge so unable to analyse any difference but number of rows returned is same.

Comment: that will be due to the data, not to the logic. I don't know what your requirement is, but if you need 2014 separate from 2015 then use year & month. if you want to combine 2014 & 2015 in a single figure by month then just use month.

Comment: I added to the previous reply, just in case you missed it

Comment: that's correct the logic of the 2 is different, they produce different results